# adb daemon started but no device detected

Tags: adb, root-access, xiaomi

I need help with adb. I'm using rooted Xiaomi Redmi 6A (Android 9). Recently, I flashed the Magisk [ADB Root](https://github.com/evdenis/adb_root) module, which is used to access `adb root` command (`adb push`, `adb pull`). This module utilizes the adbd daemon running on your phone with root rights. It did actually work, but with one problem - now I can't use adb outside of TWRP recovery.

Since I already did what I wanted to do with adb root, I uninstalled this module - but it didn't do anything. Every time I'm trying to use adb, the daemon is started successfully, but adb doesn't see any devices attached. This isn't a problem with the cable or PC - before using this module, it all worked without issues. Inside the module file, I found a `setpolicy.rule` file:

```
allow adbd adbd process setcurrent
allow adbd su process dyntransition
allow su * * *
```

I'm looking for a way to reset adb/adbd settings to default, which hopefully would fix my problem.
(I did try to contact them via their Telegram, but it seems inactive).

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the module, I think the module only replaces `adbd` daemon on Android with the patched `adbd` binary. If you have any problems after installing this module, you can uninstall them, and reboot, since the Magisk module doesn't affect your system permanently.

You can restart adb daemon on a Windows PC with `adb kill-server` and then relaunch with `adb devices`.

And make sure you activate adb on developers mode.

If you want to automatically turn on adb on boot and allow adb root, try my Magisk module: [Adb-Root-Enabler](https://github.com/anasfanani/Adb-Root-Enabler)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I did uninstalled this module and rebooted, but the problem persisted - 'adb devices' still can't see my phone. I'm hoping that if I reset all command modified by setpolicy.rule to default, it would fix my problem. Do you know the default values for these three arguments from my post?

Comment: I have no idea to revert back, afaik, magisk will not apply that sepolicy.rules after the module uninstalled, for reference, start from here, latest magisk will copy all sepolicy rules
https://github.com/vvb2060/Magisk/blob/bb39a524d05f0fb08cf4c8d9698d35e4725563d8/scripts/util_functions.sh#L715C8-L715C8

then line `584` will copy to directory `$(magisk --path)/.magisk/preinit/module_name/sepolicy.rule`,  in order to show current policy you can use `magiskpolicy`